# Fail to predict woe in R

Tags: r, prediction

I used this formula to get woe with

```
library("woe")
woe.object <- woe(data, Dependent="target", FALSE, 
                  Independent="shop_id", C_Bin=20, Bad=0, Good=1)
```

Then I want to predict woe for the test data

```
test.woe <- predict(woe.object, newdata = test, replace = TRUE)
```

And it gives me an error

> Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
>     no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Any suggestions please?

Comment: For predictions, you might have to use library(klaR)

Comment: I used it, stull giving the same error

Comment: you can see below.. however i am not sure if you run your model with woe from klar

Answer (score 0):

For prediction, you cannot do it with the package `woe`. You need to use the package. Take note of the masking of the function `woe`, see below:

```
#let's say we woe and then klaR was loaded
library(klaR)

data = data.frame(target=sample(0:1,100,replace=TRUE),
shop_id = sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE),
another_var = sample(letters[1:3],100,replace=TRUE))
#make sure both dependent and independent are factors
data$target=factor(data$target)
data$shop_id = factor(data$shop_id)
data$another_var = factor(data$another_var)
```

You need two or more dependent variables:

```
woemodel <- klaR::woe(target~ shop_id+another_var, 
data = data)
```

If you only provide one, you have an error:

```
woemodel <- klaR::woe(target~ shop_id, 
    data = data)
```

> Error in woe.default(x, grouping, weights = weights, ...) :    All
>   factors with unique levels. No woes calculated! In addition: Warning
>   message: In woe.default(x, grouping, weights = weights, ...) :   Only
>   one single input variable. Variable name in resulting object$woe is
>   only conserved in formula call.

If you want to predict the dependent variable with only one independent, something like logistic regression will work:

```
mdl = glm(target ~ shop_id,data=data,family="binomial")
prob = predict(mdl,data,type="response")
predicted_label = ifelse(prob>0.5,levels(data$target)[1],levels(data$target)[0])
```

Comment: I get always this error: Error in sum(keep.fids) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument  
whenever I run woemodel <- klaR::woe(credit_risk~ property+housing, 
data = GermanCredit[train,])

Comment: Do you know which type should woemodel be? I got the woemodel results as a dataframe from the equation I wrote with library(woe) which is an image of klaR. So when I predict using klaR it seems that the type of woe model (dataframe) is wrong.

Comment: Bottom line is, if you use predict.woe from klaR, it has to be "Object resulting from a call of ‘woe’.", meaning something returned from klaR::woe and not woe::woe

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! I meant a mirror of the package sorry. KlaR is not working with me, even by restarting R. Would you recommend me to install it from github? Would that make a difference?

Comment: I see now, you get that error because both response and predictor have to be categorical using klaR::woe.

Comment: Dependent Target is 0 or 1. Independent variable is shop_id which is categorical or char. And I would like to get woe. Then predict woe on test data which does not include the target

Comment: You need 2 or more dependent variables to use woe from klaR. I will edit my answer above to show it. If there's one, use logistic regression (https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-perform-a-logistic-regression-in-r/).

Comment: Thanks alot! I had R version 3.6.2 and I deinstalled it and installed R 3.1.2 and it worked! That's really weird! Do you know how to get the woe values when target =1 and not 0. As it sets the first value as default

Comment: change the levels? factor(data$target,levels=c(1,0)) ? or 0,1 I don't know what's yours now

Comment: Thanks! Could I ask which R version are you using? I could run woe with klaR. However I got an error when I predict: Error in applywoes(object[[i]], x.fact[, which(names(x.fact) == names(object)[i])]) : 
  Factor Levels do not match!

Comment: I am using R 3.6.1